# django - making an ordered list admin page with buttons to adjust priorities

Tags: django

Using django 1.7.7 or 1.8, what I want to do is to add an up and down button to this page:
[image]

so that I can change object orders neatly.
I saw:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2858/
but I do not understand how the javascript is loaded via the class Media.
My code:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Box(models.Model):
    material = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    priority = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('priority',)
    class Media:
        js = ['static/js/widget_ordering.js', ]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%i: %s" % (self.priority, self.material)

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Box

class BoxAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('priority', 'material')

admin.site.register(Box, BoxAdmin)
```

I already know the alternative solution being:
- making a template that extends base_site
- changing the urls.py to override the url
- writting template code and javscript to do what I need

but I think I should first ask if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: You could use [`django-suit`](http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to achieve this as it has a [built-in `ModelAdmin` class that you can make use of to provide ordering in adin list views](http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sortables.html). The obvious caveat is that you will be using their skin, changing the look and feel of your admin area.

Comment: I tried it. It was tricky because one must load suit package before the admin package in the settings.py. Also it only supports up to django 1.7 and I shall try it with django 1.8. Another concern is that I already have custom pages that extend base_site which now need to be adjusted. On the positive side, django-suit license is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

`django-mptt` has support for Django 1.8+ and has a built in [admin base class](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/admin.html#mptt-admin-draggablempttadmin) with drag and drop.  I doesn't have up and down buttons as requested, but drag and drop should be good enough.

[image: DraggableMPTTAdmin Screenshot]

I doesn't only support ordering, but also trees.  MPTT stands for Modified Preorder Tree Traversal.

- [documentation](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/)
- [github](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt)
- [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mptt) ([warehouse](https://pypi.org/project/django-mptt/))